# DateTime property stays at 01/01/0001

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller

I have this simple adding to db method and I keep getting this error

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated"

In the debugger I see that the date rendered is "01/01/0001 00:00:00". I'm almost sure this is not today, as I set it through `DateTime.Now`.

```
public class UDetails
{
    [Key]
    public string UDetailsId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Your name")]
    public string UName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "my DOB is publich")]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    public string Gender  { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegesterDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Occupation")]
    public string OccupationDecription { get; set; }

    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public int OccupationId { get; set; }
}

var entity = new UDetails()
{
    UserPhoto = model.UserPhoto,
    DOB = model.DOB,
    IsPublic = model.IsPublic,
    Gender = model.Gender,
    OccupationDecription = model.OccupationDecription
};
model.Email = User.Identity.Name;
model.RegesterDate = DateTime.Now;
model.UDetailsId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

db.udetails.Add(entity);
db.SaveChanges();
return View("index");
```

Comment: Does the name of the property (RegesterDate) matches the column name in the database?

Comment: Only almost sure? :) You're also not setting `RegesterDate` (as well as `email` and `udetailsid`) - you're setting it on the model. Is that correct? It's likely because your columns in the database are not nullable.

Comment: You are not adding the date to the entity object. Than you save that entity which is missing the RegesterDate. This 01/01/0001 is the default value for Datetime.

Comment: My MS-SQL script:CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UDetails] (
    [DOB]                  DATETIME       NULL,  [RegesterDate]         DATETIME       NULL, when it was not null I had the same issue

Comment: As others have indicated, you're simply forgetting to set `entity.RegesterDate`. You're setting it on the model.

Comment: you didn't add value to RegesterDate. That's why.

Comment: entity.RegesterDate = DateTime.Now; Solve the problem , As CodeCaster say , thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the RegesterDate to a model (probably is your parameter). This should fix:

```
var entity = new UDetails()
{
    // ...

    Email = User.Identity.Name,
    RegesterDate = DateTime.Now,
    UDetailsId = User.Identity.GetUserId()      

    // ...
};
```